# Least squares method

Tags: python

I have a set of data that follows a double gaussian distribution, whose equation depends on 4 parameters. What I'd like to do is:

- starting from a value for each of the 4 parameters (that are the ones I know that are closer to the parameters of the double gaussian that I obtain from the set of data)
- increasing them step by step
- plot the double gaussian with these parameters
- and check, using the least squares method, which are the better values to plot a double gaussian that is the best fit for the double gaussian that I obtain with the set of data.

I've tried to do it, below is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def DGauss(x,I1,I2,sigma1,sigma2):
    return (I1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma1))*np.exp(-x*x/(2*sigma1*sigma1)) + (I2/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma2))*np.exp(-x*x/(2*sigma2*sigma2))

def Inte(x0,xf,npoints,I1,I2,sigma1,sigma2):
     delta = (xf-x0)/npoints
     h = 0
     for i in range(npoints):
         x = x0 + i*delta
         if (i % 2) == 0:
             fact = 4.0
         else:
             fact = 2.0 

         h += fact*DGauss(x,I1,I2,sigma1,sigma2)

     return (abs(delta)/3.0)*(h + DGauss(x0,I1,I2,sigma1,sigma2) + DGauss(xf,I1,I2,sigma1,sigma2))

def IntBLM(start,end):
    delta = 1
    VarIntBLM = (1.0/3.0)*(BLM[start]+4.0*BLM[start+delta]+BLM[end])
    return VarIntBLM

Position = [9.88, 8.68, 7.48, 6.28, 5.08, 3.88, 3.28, 3.13, 3.08, 3.03, 2.98, 2.93, 2.88, 2.83, 2.78, 2.73, 2.68, 2.63, 2.58, 2.53, 2.48, 2.43, 2.38, 2.33, 2.28, 2.23, 2.18, 2.13, 2.08, 2.03, 1.98, 1.93, 1.88, 1.83, 1.78, 1.73, 1.68, 1.63, 1.58, 1.53, 1.48, 1.43, 1.38, 1.33, 1.28, 1.23, 1.18, 1.13, 1.08, 1.03, 0.98, 0.93, 0.88, 0.83, 0.78, 0.73, 0.68, 0.63, 0.58, 0.53, 0.48, 0.43, 0.38, 0.33, 0.28, 0.23, 0.18, 0.13, 0.08, 0.03]

yVal = [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.05493778e-04, 3.68936803e-04, 1.73977308e-03, 9.86279398e-03, 1.52954321e-02, 2.42624032e-02, 2.87455974e-02, 3.23848413e-02, 3.28592719e-02, 3.94523416e-02, 4.61509051e-02, 5.70161813e-02, 6.37672003e-02, 7.19426767e-02, 7.76393407e-02, 8.56568678e-02, 9.61526244e-02, 1.04328101e-01, 1.13506059e-01, 1.19940597e-01, 1.26006198e-01, 1.40933276e-01, 1.50796653e-01, 1.66514643e-01, 1.80650226e-01, 1.93889404e-01, 2.04754098e-01, 2.17940237e-01, 2.28067057e-01, 2.37930434e-01, 2.51644042e-01, 2.63511800e-01, 2.80759742e-01, 2.95686820e-01, 3.08715010e-01, 3.31184602e-01, 3.46480617e-01, 3.69846614e-01, 3.85406655e-01, 4.06188347e-01, 4.28394495e-01, 4.50020137e-01, 4.83039107e-01, 5.07460625e-01, 5.31670573e-01, 5.54879204e-01, 5.78351278e-01, 6.02561809e-01, 6.25664363e-01, 6.57048471e-01, 6.82893863e-01, 7.13327944e-01, 7.32580267e-01, 7.69608000e-01, 7.87699892e-01, 8.14072753e-01, 8.33588519e-01, 8.52102386e-01, 8.71090683e-01, 8.94562175e-01, 9.16187816e-01, 9.37602470e-01, 9.56802338e-01, 9.69197565e-01, 9.78321903e-01, 9.84861934e-01, 9.93142904e-01,]

BLM = [0., 0., 0., 0.000181, 0.000452, 0.002352, 0.000724, 0.000633, 0.001267, 0.000633, 0.006244, 0.000814, 0.002805, 0.000633, 0.002443, 0.000814,0.001629, 0.001086, 0.001448, 0.001357, 0.002443, 0.001991, 0.002805, 0.010407,0.001991, 0.000814, 0.002352, 0.002714, 0.002081, 0.002714, 0.002352, 0.00181, 0.004253, 0.001719, 0.003077, 0.001448, 0.002805, 0.002896, 0.002986, 0.0019, 0.002262, 0.002262, 0.004072, 0.004434, 0.006425, 0.002986, 0.005701, 0.002352,0.004163, 0.004615, 0.001991, 0.001538, 0.005158, 0.0019,   0.003981, 0.004615,0.004615, 0.003167, 0.005339, 0.003619, 0.005339, 0.00181,  0.002624, 0.001267, 0.0038, 0.001629, 0.002986, 0.000633, 0.001719, 0.000543]

npoints = 13 
npairs = 13


hMin = 1
h=0

for k in range(13):
    sigma1 = 0.01*(k+1) + 1
    for l in range(13):
        sigma2 = 0.01*(l+1) + 1
        for m in range(13):
            I1 = 0.1*(m+1)
            for j in range(13):
                I2 = 0.1*(j+1)
                for i in range(13):
                    startPos = 50+i 
                    endPos = 52+i 
                    startX = Position[startPos]
                    endX = Position[endPos]

                    h += (IntBLM(startPos,endPos)-Inte(startX,endX,npoints,I1,I2,sigma1,sigma2))**2

                if h < hMin:
                    hMin = h
                    I1min = I1
                    I2min = I2
                    sigma1min = sigma1
                    sigma2min = sigma2

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(Position,yVal,'o')
plt.plot(Position,DGauss(Posi,I1min,I2min,sigma1min,sigma2min), label='Least Square')
plt.show()
```

I've done different tests, printing the values of the gaussian parameters, the value returned by the least squares method, but the problem is that the values of `I1min, I2min, sigma1min, sigma2min` are always the ones obtained from the first cycle of the loop, and the value of `I1min` is always equal to `I2min`, link the value of `sigma1min` is equal to `sigma2min`, and I know that this isn't right. Could anyone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: Off topic: be careful with: giving functions the name of types (Int) and giving variables the name of functions (IntBLM). Python is meant to be a readable language, but as a programmer it is still in your own hands how readable the code is. You can find more about Python's naming conventions (from PEP) [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#naming-conventions).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've proceeded to modify the script, even if the result has not changed.

Comment: What is the purpose of the condition `if h < hMin:`?

Comment: Rereading the definition of least squares method, I've changed the code. The least squares method is an optimization technique that allows us to find a function, represented by an optimal curve, that is as close as possible to a set of data. In particular, the function found must be that which minimizes the sum of the squares of the distances between the observed data and those of the curve that represents the function itself. Therefore the purpose of the condition is to find the minimum value of the sum of the squares of the distances.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the logic is thus:

1. `hMin = 1`, `h=0`

   2. `h += (IntBLM(startPos,endPos)-Int(startX,endX,npoints,I1,I2,sigma1,sigma2))**2`
      a. **if** `h` is greater than or equal to 1, the conditional never executes
      b. **else if** `h` is now between 0 and 1, the conditional executes

      1. `hMin = h`
         Now, `h` will **never** be less than `hMin`, since it always *increases* by a positive amount (a squared value). Thus the conditional never executes again, and `I1min, I2min, sigma1min, sigma2min` maintain their instantiated values

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the point a. and b., instead for the point 1. I agree with you, because I have tried to print also `h` and it is always greater then the value returned by the first cycle, even if some times decreases, but always remains greater than the value returned from the first cycle. I hope I've explained well what I wolud like to do, otherwise do not hesitate to ask me clarification. Do you have any suggestions on how to edit the script? Thanks

Comment: @XaBla The first time the loop runs, b happens. All subsequent times, a happens. The script runs as expected, because the condition `h < hMin` is only true the first time the loop runs. If you want the logic in the conditional to be executed under a different condition, you need to change the condition. Or change what happens to h and/or hMin so the condition is fulfilled as many times as you expect it to be.

Comment: OK, now the points a. and b. are clearer, thank you! I've also tried to change `h += (IntBLM(startPos,endPos)-Int(startX,endX,npoints,I1,I2,sigma1,sigma2))**2`, in `h = (IntBLM(startPos,endPos)-Int(startX,endX,npoints,I1,I2,sigma1,sigma2))**2`, . following your observation, since the value of h was always increased by a positive value. In this way the value of `h` will always and only be equal to the value returned by the least squares method. However this is still not enough.

Comment: As for the equations of `h` and `hMin`, I think they are right. You could better explain what you mean with "change the condition. Or change what happens to h and/or hMin", please?

Comment: @XaBla well, that's the thing - I don't know how many times you expect it to run, or what are the actual conditions you want it to run under. You have already made some progress correcting an error with how `h` is modified, but you say `"However this is still not enough."` - I can't help you here if I don't know what value you expect `h`/`hMin` to have each loop (i.e. work out why the values they actually take aren't these).

Comment: This is the point, I don't know in advance which are the values that I sould get, so it should run it as many times as necessary, so that the value of `hMin` is as small as possible. In doing so, in fact, I would obtain the values of the parameters for which the plotted double Gaussian (with the parameters found) is as similar as possible to the double Gaussian plotted with the dataset that I originally have.

Comment: The reason why I know that the values I get now are not the right ones is that if I try to plot the two double Gaussians, they don't match, or at least the trend of one doesn't tend to follow the trend of the other one plotted with the data set.